# Streaming - how to get song name with AVAsset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am trying to load a strong from an URL and get the title of the currently playing song.

Song is playing. Everything is nice till I hit this "get the songTitle" wall. Sadly `NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);` doesn't return anything. Pretty much stuck here.

```
AVURLAsset *newAsset =[AVURLAsset assetWithURL:audioFileURL];
    [newAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus durationStatus = [newAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"commonMetadata" error:&error];

        switch (durationStatus) {
            case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: {
                playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:newAsset];
                self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

                NSArray *songMeta = [newAsset commonMetadata];

                for (AVMetadataItem *item in songMeta ) {
                    NSString *key = [item commonKey];
                    NSString *value = [item stringValue];
                    NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);
                }

                break;
            }
            case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Default");
                break;
        }
    }];
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the song you load actually have any metadata?

Comment: Don't think this matters, but I've always seen NSError *error. not NSError *error = nil.

Comment: @sch it is possible there is none but I know for sure the stream sends the name. what other ways are there of sending the song name except metadata?

Comment: @Eric you might be right. I am currently learning. probably a mistake. I'll look into it. Thanks